# Linear Equations solution for only 1 known RHS constant

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 2 variables x and y, and 4 linear equations as follows:

$$\begin{equation}
 C1 \,x  =a,\\
 C2\,x + C3\,y =b,\\
 C4\,x + C5\,y =c,\\
 C6\,x + C7\,y =d.\\
\end{equation} 
$$

where $ C1, C2,...,C7 $ are some known real number constants and $a,b,c,d$ are unknown constants that I want to find. The constraint here is sum of $x,y$ and all these equations is $1$, i.e.

$$a + b + c + d + x + y = 1$$

So we have another equation with known RHS constant,

$$  C8\;x + C9\; y = 1 $$

Is there any solution to this system and how to solve this system?

Answer (score 0):

*Linear programming:*

Not only you should solve, but also know what to solve including what not to solve.

When equations are too many compared to the number of unknowns, we term it as *overdetermined*, you cannot solve for all the variables. You don't need to.

To decide which of the lines determined by straight lines are a constraint, at first sketch all lines in the first quadrant and *eliminate* those that are far away.

You need to solve only those lines that "enter into competition" to find relevant points of intersection.

Comment: As stated, the question is not about linear programming, it's an *underdetermined* linear system (6 unknowns, 5 equations).

Comment: OK, to go further he has to define *some* criterion .

Comment: Or simply solve the system with a parameter in the solution, as is customary in such cases. Anyway you are right, something does not look perfectly clear in the question.

Comment: Thanks, if you so suggest I shall modify or delete my answer..

Comment: Let's wait a bit. I'm not even sure the problem is not related to linear programming in some way. :)

Comment: hello all, so what kind of constraint should be applied? can u give a hint or idea?? it will be very helpful...